# regular expression to remove matching values in comma separated string

Tags: regex

I have 2 strings which are comma-separated

- main_string :   USA,India,Russia,UK
- sub_string :    India,UK

I want to remove all values found in sub_string from my main_string

example output    main_string :   USA,Russia

What is the regular expression pattern I can use here?

Comment: You can't solve this in a single regex at least, you'll need a higher-level language. And once you're using a higher-level language, there won't be much use for regex to solve that task, just split around commas and use plain-text search

Comment: Do you just want to capture every other string between the commas?

Answer (score -1):

Does `(\w+),(\w+)` work with a substitution of `$1` work for you?

https://regex101.com/r/6RvE5J/2/